# Should you do muscle-ups everyday for optimal improvement?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

I couldn't find any information about this on google, so I'm asking here.

My answer is yes because it's not that power-draining, more like technical skill, thus hard to overtrain. As long as I properly warm up first, do you think it is possible to do muscle-ups every day without overtraining?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do muscle ups everyday, but I do not think it is the best way of improving. Also I think muscle-ups are more "draining" than you give it credit.

Consult calisthenics and gymnastics workout routines.

Comment: I can't do that many muscle ups my max is about 7. But when I for example do 7 muscle ups I don't feel particular very exhausted compared to when I max out on pull ups

Comment: With pull-ups you are experiencing muscle fatigue. With muscle ups you may be experiencing other types of fatigue. Central nervous system fatigue may affect your reaction time. Limited oxygen may affect your muscle performance. A more constructive route may be to ask a separate question, "how do I increase my max muscle ups?".